# is there a TranslateAnimation onComplete?

Tags: android, animation

I am animating a view to move off the screen, on complete i would like to call another function but I cant seem to find a onComplete method.

```
int originalPos[] = new int[2];
                icons.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );
                layoutMoved = originalPos[0]+icons.getWidth();
                TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, -layoutMoved , 0, 0);
                anim.setDuration(500);
                anim.setFillAfter( true );
                icons.startAnimation(anim);
                icons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an [AnimationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html), you'll have access to OnAnimationEnd.

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
       // do your stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```